# How to execute a background task only for once in windows phone 8.1 universal app

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

In my application after first login/registration I need to download data from server this will take some time. And user can quit the application while data is loading. So I need to download the data in background process. I know I can use backgorund application/Class and register this class in windows phone application but this is only for one time. Is there any other way to do so without creating backgourd task for this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help,

You're looking for `BackgroundDownloader` and `DownloadOperation` in the Windows.Networking.BackgroundTransfer namespace.

```C#
BackgroundDownloader downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
DownloadOperation download = downloader.CreateDownload(source, destinationFile);
```

---

[MSDN Windows.Networking.BackgroundTransfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer)

---

[Background Transfer Sample Project  (Windows Universal)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Transfer-Sample-d7833f61)